# Python for loop where both if statements need to execute

Tags: python, django, for-loop

I edited my question so it is easier to understand the problem.

I have a django table, which consists of IP addreses and must show in real time which of those are currently permited or not permited, and based on status, if address is permited then change it's status to not permited and vice versa.

For that function I have checkbox column, which collects row column values(like ip address, id, etc.) when it is checked and posts those with submit button(post request). Basically, I need to execute telnet commands, permit/not permit ip by use of a checkbox.

In views.py I collect ids of checkbox with: 
pks = request.POST.getlist("Checkbox").

Then I get values of row columns in lists.

```
selected_objects = Model.objects.filter(pk__in=pks)
result = [selected_objects.get(pk=item).column name for item in pks]
result2=...
```

After that I run telnet script. 
Here I get router configuration as list, which I compare to ip addreses in table(if statement in for loop-prefix_list-router configuration/liste-selected table ips).
Also here I have tn.write commands were I am trying to put these list values. Example:

```
tn.write(b"no ip prefix-list LISTNAME seq " + result[y].encode('ascii') + b" permit " +result1[y].encode('ascii') + b"\n")
```

And here for loop comes into the play, because I have to loop through these lists (y is index):

```
for y in range(len(result)):
    if [item for item in liste if item in prefix_list]:
        tn.write(b"no ip prefix-list LISTNAME seq " + result[y].encode('ascii') + b" permit " +result1[y].encode('ascii') + b"\n")
        time.sleep(1)
    if [item for item in liste if item not in prefix_list]:
        tn.write(b"ip prefix-list LISTNAME seq " + result[y].encode('ascii') + b" permit " +result1[y].encode('ascii') + b"\n")
        time.sleep(1)
```

So far everything is working except occasion when I, for example, permit one ip address and not permit another (script works when I only permit or only not permit).

I am in no way an expert so feel free to let me know what I am doing wrong or could do better.

Comment: Y have you not used if else instead of two "ifs" ..any reason ?

Comment: As I understand if I use if else (elif), the code will execute only when the first if statement is false, however what I need is when I select two values (one is in both lists, other not in both lists) to execute both ifs or if and else. The problem is that in my case if statement works and else statement does not.

Comment: What is the purpose of the outer for loop here, since it doesn't seem to effect the if conditions in any way

Comment: Could you make your code more clear, your explanation make it even more confusing. You write that you have taken `value[y]` in the `if` condition, but you are looping over `List1`. Could you update your question so that you assign example values for `value`, `List1` and `List2` and explain what you expect to happen for these example values?

Answer (score 1):

> if one of if statements is true it ignores the second if statement

What you are describing is not true, you are confusing it with an `if` `elif(else if)` construct.

Example:

```
x = 3
if x<5:
    print("<5")
elif x<10:
    print("<10")
```

vs

```
x = 3
if x<5:
    print("<5")
if x<10:
    print("<10")
```

In the first example it will only print `<5` because the `if` condition is true, therefore the `elif` is not tested. In the second example you have two seperate if conditions that are evaluated independently. Therefore it will print both `<5` and `<10` since both conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my problem. Fixed it by doing two comparisons and doing two for loops.